# How to extend Tooltip Range in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, tooltip

How can i extend the Tooltip area in the [Combo-Meteogram](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-meteogram) example, so that the tooltip also shows if you go over the wind-arrows?

I can't find an any option in [Highcharts Tooltip](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip) which gives me that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those arrows are not plotted but are rendered using the `chart.renderer`.  So you need to trigger the tooltip yourself.  See this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002162/highcharts-custom-renderer-chart-and-tooltip) which is kinda close to what you want.

Applying the ideas in that answer modify the the end of the `drawWindArrows` function like so:

```
.add()
.on('mouseover', function () {
 chart.tooltip.refresh([Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].points[point.index],
                        Highcharts.charts[0].series[1].points[point.index],
                        Highcharts.charts[0].series[2].points[point.index]]);
})
.on('mouseout', function () {
 chart.tooltip.hide();
});
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dq5q78xL/).

Note, this isn't perfect.  It requires you to mouseover the arrow and not the box.  If I have time tonight or tomorrow morning, I'll fix that. :)

**EDITS**

To fix the problems you mention in your comment, just make the code a bit more dynamic:

```
.on('mouseover', function () {
    var points = $.map(point.series.chart.series, function(i){
        return i.points[point.index];
     });
     chart.tooltip.refresh(points);
})
.on('mouseout', function () {
     chart.tooltip.hide();
});
```

To fix the problem I mention, I've added an transparent shape on top of the arrow so that the mouseover will have a larger target:

```
chart.renderer.circle(x, y, 15)
    .attr({
    'stroke-width': 0,
    stroke: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
    fill: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
    zIndex: 10
}).add()
```

Updated [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/dq5q78xL/1/).

Comment: I'm still playing with your answer. My personal problem is, that your example will fail if there is more than one chart on the page or gives problems if you just add another series...

Comment: i changed to much in my chart, so that this isn't working like i want it to. I have to try more and you gave me the right idea how to do it. just one thing. the tooltip (also if i extend the radius of the circle) doesn't work the same way as in the "normal" chart field. e.g. you can "catch" the tooltip in the wind arrows part, but not in the chart itself. But you helped me a lot and answered my question very good, so i accept your answer as correct answer :)

Comment: @Neysor, not sure what you mean by "doesn't work the same way as in the "normal" chart field".  The wind arrows aren't part of the "chart".  It's actually drawn on top of the xaxis.

Comment: i know that. In my special chart i also made other extends on the bottom of that. But in the chart itself the tooltip works so "fluent" and on the arrows (also if you extend the circle range) feel so choppy. Also you can move your mouse so fast, that you can get into the tooltip and loose the "mouseover" of the transparent circle, which never happens in the normal chart. Thanks for your help, i will try to solve this problem by my own now. Your tipps helped to get into the right direction! Thanks!